# HTML to PDF using iText External CSS

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, flying-saucer

I am using Flying Saucer to render some PDF documents from strings to HTML.

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Document doc = builder.parse(is);

response.setContentType("application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + outFileName + "\"");

OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();
iTextRenderer.setDocument(doc,null);
iTextRenderer.layout();
iTextRenderer.createPDF(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

This works fine When I have plain text. 
I have referenced an external CSS in my HTML content. But, When PDF gets generated CSS doesn't get applied.

I have read that The `setDocument()` method takes two parameters: document and url. The url parameter indicates the base url used to prepend to relative paths that appear in the xhtml, such as an external CSS

So, I have tried to supply

> context path/css

direcotry in the baseURL and used it in the `setDocument()`. Still no result

So, My Question What is the correct URL to pass as baseURL ?

```
String baseURL = ""; // What goes here as root URL for resources
iTextRenderer.setDocument(doc,baseURL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_use_the_setDocument%28...%29_constructor?) tells this:

> The url is the "base", which for a normal URL would be the parent
>   location—the parent directory, or the location where the document you
>   are rendering is located.If your document has absolute URIs for CSS
>   and images, or it has no external references at all, then the base url
>   can be null.If your document has any relative URIs for CSS or images,
>   then the base URL should not be null, but rather should point to the
>   directory or address where the current document is located.

Did you test the path to your document instead of the path to your css? However, i had some trouble with linking CSS too so i inserted the URI (no problems so far :-) ). If you use a link as i posted above, does it work?

*Sorry for new post, but comments told me i have only negative char's left ...*

Comment: Can you please explain "Sorry for new post, but comments told me i have only negative char's left ...". I didn't mean anything sarcastic in my comment. And Second, Yes It works with Absolute URLs.

Comment: No, no :-) My post was too long for the comments. The length is limited so i was unable to post it.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the CSS paths by putting
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file://path/to/your.css" />`
into your document (head).

(In some cases you can use a simple path instead of an URI)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I know that it if you pass absolute URL.(I have already mentioned it :D)  But, there is something called "baseURL" which allows to provide path upto your resource directory. Any pointers on that ?

Comment: There is another question if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059807/utf-encoded-data-works-with-jsp-but-not-when-export-pdf-using-xmlworkerhelper

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the filepath, the problem is the media. One thing is to render to screen and other to render to print media like a pdf file. So you need to add an attribute to the stylesheet TAG inside your XML file.

From code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/FAQPDF

> **My PDF isn't picking up my CSS!**
>
> > PDF is treated as "print" media; see the CSS 2.1 specification section
> >     on media types. Make sure you have specified the media type for your
> >     CSS when you link or embed it; use type "print" or "all".

The quick answer is to add the attribute  `media="all"` to the XML stylesheet TAG like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="foo.css" media="all" type="text/css"?>
```

alternative you can use  `media="print"`